# Check if a contract implements specific ABI using JSON-RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, json-rpc, contract-invocation, python

In my Python web service, I'd like to confirm if a contract supports specific ABI (certain call methods). I am running get and communicating over JSON RPC.

What are steps to for this? I am guessing it's along the lines to use some RPC method to fetch contract code, decompile it and then check for presence of sha3 signatures of known methods.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question that never got answered, but it can be easily done by accessing this web API: https://www.4byte.directory

Comment: Note that this only works for function signatures that are in that database. It allows self-submission and also scrapes etherscan for solidity sources

Comment: Agreed. Are there other sources? I can imagine a search algorithm that first tries 4byte, then etherscan, then whatever, but I would imagine that those two would provide nearly all available info. (That last is just a guess.)